# How can consume pagemethod on difference page

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I search the web and didn't find the solution about consume pagemethod on difference pages. I have a PageMethod to set the specific Session variable on aspx page. Now I have other aspx pages and need to the same thing.  I must use javascript to call the pagemethod. Do I need to create the same PageMethod on the every apsx page? If not, how can I call the pagemethod on pageA.aspx from pageB.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the purpose of the method is same, create a static class and put the method there and call that method everywhere.

Comment: @Prash, I must use javascript to call the pagemethod. Do I need to have the pagemethod on every pages on code behind?

Comment: Yes. Got it. So better option is to have a static method defined somewhere. Because, currently you have a method in your page, which would be instance method. If you try to invoke it from a different page it wouldn't work, as other page instance doesn't exist. So instead, I advise you to have a static method to be declared in your common library/class, and use that method throughout. Post your current code for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling arbitrary page method is as easy as making a POST request

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest()
x.open("POST", "/Page.aspx/PageMethodName", true)
x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
x.send('{"Hello":"PageMethod!"}') // or JSON.stringify()
```

Might be enough to hit your goal!